# Array math on numpy structured arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=[('c1', float), ('c2', float)])
arr += 3
```

results in an invalid type promotion error. Is there a way I can have nice labeled columns like a structured array, but still be able to do operations like it's a simple `dtype=float` array?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to cast a `dtype=float` array into a structured array? i.e.

```
arr = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=float)
arr_struc = arr.astype([('c1', float), ('c2', float)])
```

only where it doesn't broadcast and matches columns to names. Seems like I shouldn't have to do this loop:

```
arr_struc = np.zeros(2, dtype=[('c1', float), ('c2', float)])
for i,key in enumerate(arr_struc.dtype.names):  arr_struc[key] = arr[i,:]
```

Comment: On the structured array docs page, they describe the `numpy.lib.recfunctions` module.  In has a `structured_to_unstructured` and `unstructured_to_structured` functions.    A `view` if it works is faster, but these are more general purpose.

Comment: A key thing to keep in mind when doing your own conversion is that data for a structured array is in the form of a list of tuples, while unstructured displays as list of lists.  But using structured arrays just to have pretty 'column' names is, I think, more work than its worth.  Structured arrays are best when fields have distinct dtypes, esp. some numeric, and others string.

Comment: Yes, just use a `.view` again, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. One option, use a view for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=[('c1', float), ('c2', float)])
>>> view = arr.view(float)
>>> view += 3
>>> arr
array([(4., 5.), (6., 7.)], dtype=[('c1', '<f8'), ('c2', '<f8')])
>>> view
array([4., 5., 6., 7.])
```

Not the cleanest. But it's a solution.

EDIT:

Yes, don't use `astype` use *a view again*:

```
>>> arr = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=float)
>>> arr
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])
>>> struct = arr.view(dtype=[('c1', float), ('c2', float)])
>>> struct
array([[(1., 2.)],
       [(3., 4.)]], dtype=[('c1', '<f8'), ('c2', '<f8')])
>>> struct.shape
(2, 1)
```

You may have to reshape it to your liking:

```
>>> struct.squeeze()
array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.)], dtype=[('c1', '<f8'), ('c2', '<f8')])
```

Comment: That's a good way. I guess for my purposes I could also do most of the math on the float array, then convert it at the end. Is there an elegant way to do that (i.e., without a loop)? `arr.astype([('c1', '<f8'), ('c2', '<f8')])` doesn't behave like I'd want.

Comment: @I.P.Freeley I don't follow, can you edit your question and elaborate?